# How to build a json object given a list of fields (key -> value) in Scala

Tags: json, scala, play-json

I am looking for a solution on how to create and/or append multiple fields to a `play.api.libs.json.JsObject`. I have a **list** of (string -> JsValue) in which I don't know how many there are, nor specifically which field names are available.

`Json.obj` does accepts multiple fields, but looks like you cannot pass in a list. Instead you need to specifically pass all the fields in like this:

```
Json.obj((k1 -> v1), (k2 -> v2), ...)
```

Which won't work for my use case. I would want something like this instead:

```
Json.obj(listOfFields) // listOfFields: List[(String, JsValue)]
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By having a look at the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsObject$.html), it's visible that `JsObject` companion `extends (Seq[(String, JsValue)]) ⇒ JsObject`, so rather than calling `Json.obj` (with extra conversion):

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._

def foo(fields: List[(String, JsValue)]): JsObject = JsObject(fields)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that specific library, but this should break the list into a set of separate arguments:

```
Json.obj(listOfFields:_*)
```